# How do you generate an RGBA image in Core Graphics?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, core-graphics

I'm trying to generate an RGBA8 image from text to use as an OpenGL ES 2.0 texture.

```
+(UIImage *)imageFromText:(NSString *)text
{
  UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0];  
  CGSize size  = [text sizeWithFont:font];

  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
  CGContextRef contextRef =  CGBitmapContextCreate (NULL,
                                                    size.width, size.height,
                                                    8, 4*size.width,
                                                    colorSpace,
                                                    kCGImageAlphaLast
                                                    );
  CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
  UIGraphicsPushContext(contextRef);

  [text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) withFont:font];
  UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  UIGraphicsPopContext();

  return image;
}
```

Unfortunately, there's no `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGBA`, and `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB` results in the following error:

```
CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 8 integer bits/component; 32 bits/pixel; 3-component color space; kCGImageAlphaLast; 448 bytes/row.
```

What am I missing to create the proper RGBA8 format that OpenGL wants here?

*Update*: I changed the last parameter of `CGBitmapContextCreate` from `kCGImageAlphaNone` (which it was when I copy pasted the code) to `kCGImageAlphaLast`, which is one of several variations I've tried in error.

*Update 2*: `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` returns nil if the context was not created with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()`, so it is necessary to extract the image differently: `[UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage(contextRef)]`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The color space you specify during creation wouldn't cause an error like that.

The reason you're getting that error is that you've specified 8 bits per component, presumably 4 color components in the `4*size.width` value you passed in for `bytesPerRow`, yet a `bitmapInfo` parameter of `kCGImageAlphaNone`. `kCGImageAlphaNone` means only `RGB`, not `RGBA`. If you want `RGBA`, you should most likely specify <s>`kCGImageAlphaLast`</s> `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast`.

[EDIT] sorry. I should have said `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast`, not `kCGImageAlphaLast`.

So, something like this:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);
CGContextRef contextRef =  CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                 size.width,
                                                 size.height,
                                                 8,
                                                 4 * size.width,
                                                 colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
```

Comment: I had tried that as well; unfortunately I receive the same (ish) error: "CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 8 integer bits/component; 32 bits/pixel; 3-component color space; kCGImageAlphaLast; 448 bytes/row."

Comment: I've updated the question to show that the error still occurs with kCGImageAlphaLast.

Comment: @Ian Terrell: Yup, sorry, I was mistaken; see my updated answer with `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` rather than `kCGImageAlphaLast`.

Comment: That does fix the error; my UIImage was further created incorrectly, but I resolved that via image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGBitmapContextCreateImage(contextRef)]. Thanks!

Comment: Apple docs say that kCGImageAlphaXX is supported since 2.0 but really only kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedXXX seems to work.

Comment: I'm sorry, but according to the SDK the last parameter on the CGBitmapContextCreate should be a CGBitmapInfo, not a CGImageAlpha constant.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGBitmapContextCreate

Comment: @RobvanderVeer: A `CGBitmapInfo` includes a `CGImageAlphaInfo` as part of the mask. From (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGBitmapContextCreate): "The constants for specifying the alpha channel information are declared with the `CGImageAlphaInfo` type but can be passed to this parameter safely. You can also pass the other constants associated with the `CGBitmapInfo` type."

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same `unsupported parameter combination` error even though I was using `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast`. The issue in my case turned out to be that the width I was getting was fractional. Turning it into an integer by passing `int(width)` to CGBitmapContextCreate solved the problem.

--Edit in response to Steven's comment--

The issue with feeding in a fractional width as the second argument is not that `CGBitmapContextCreate` interprets it as such -- as stated, it gets casted implicitly to the argument's unsigned integer type. Rather, it produces a discrepancy in the `bytes_per_row` argument, since int(width * 4) is not the same as int(width) * 4. E.g. if the width is 22.5, then width gets truncated to 22, but `width * 4` computes to 90, not 88.

Comment: Impossible, the width argument to `CGBitmapContextCreate ` is already an (unsigned) integer. The casting is done for you.

Comment: The note reported an observation, therefore it is not impossible by definition, because it has occurred. Having said that, my analysis was incomplete. I have edited my response and clarified why using a fractional width is a problem.

Comment: True, I was questioning the observations/measurement. Thanks for clarifying. By the way, if you're using NULL for the data argument like the OP, you also pass 0 for bytes per row so the system can choose a correct (and perhaps even more performant) value.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);

    CGBitmapInfo    bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little;

    CGContextRef theContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, imgSize.width, imgSize.height, 8, 4*imgSize.width, colorSpace, bitmapInfo);
```