# opencv ios transparent image loaded without transparency

Tags: ios, opencv

I'm, developing an ios application that uses some opencv functionality (remove background, edge detections etc.)

Amongst other things, I load transparent images (pngs). From some reason when I load the images opencv decides to ignore some transparent areas while respecting others. I can see this by converting my semi transparent UIImage to an IplImage and then back to UIImage (without doing any operation on the iplimage) and saving both images to the local file.

This is the code I'm using for converting the UIImage to an IplImage and backwards:

```
- (IplImage *)CreateIplImageFromUIImageWithTransparency:(UIImage *)image {
    // Getting CGImage from UIImage
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    // Creating temporal IplImage for drawing
    IplImage *iplimage = cvCreateImage(
                                       cvSize(image.size.width,image.size.height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4
                                       );
    // Creating CGContext for temporal IplImage
    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                                                    iplimage->imageData, iplimage->width, iplimage->height,
                                                    iplimage->depth, iplimage->widthStep,
                                                    colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault
                                                    );
    // Drawing CGImage to CGContext
    CGContextDrawImage(
                       contextRef,
                       CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height),
                       imageRef
                       );
    CGContextRelease(contextRef);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Creating result IplImage
    IplImage *ret = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(iplimage), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
    cvCvtColor(iplimage, ret, CV_RGBA2BGRA);
    cvReleaseImage(&iplimage);

    return ret;
}


- (UIImage *)UIImageFromIplImage:(IplImage *)image {
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:image->imageData length:image->imageSize];
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(image->width, image->height,
                                        image->depth, image->depth * image->nChannels, image->widthStep,
                                        colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaLast ,
                                        provider, NULL, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    UIImage *ret = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    return ret;
}
```

What could be causing this behavior?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This code works for me. I modified the code from [here](https://github.com/aptogo/OpenCVForiPhone/blob/master/OpenCVClient/UIImage+OpenCV.mm)

Reading from UIImage

```
-(cv::Mat)CVMat
{

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage);
    CGFloat cols = self.size.width;
    CGFloat rows = self.size.height;

    cv::Mat cvMat(rows, cols, CV_8UC4); // 8 bits per component, 4 channels

    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data,                 // Pointer to backing data
                                                    cols,                      // Width of bitmap
                                                    rows,                     // Height of bitmap
                                                    8,                          // Bits per component
                                                    cvMat.step[0],              // Bytes per row
                                                    colorSpace,                 // Colorspace
                                                    //kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast |
                                                    kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast |
                                                    kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault); // Bitmap info flags

    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), self.CGImage);
    CGContextRelease(contextRef);

    return cvMat;
}
```

Converting back to UIImage:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithCVMat:(const cv::Mat&)cvMat
{
    return [[UIImage alloc] initWithCVMat:cvMat];
}

- (id)initWithCVMat:(const cv::Mat&)cvMat
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize() * cvMat.total()];

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

    if (cvMat.elemSize() == 1)
    {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    }
    else
    {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(cvMat.cols,                                     // Width
                                        cvMat.rows,                                     // Height
                                        8,                                              // Bits per component
                                        8 * cvMat.elemSize(),                           // Bits per pixel
                                        cvMat.step[0],                                  // Bytes per row
                                        colorSpace,                                     // Colorspace
                                        kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,  // Bitmap info flags
                                        provider,                                       // CGDataProviderRef
                                        NULL,                                           // Decode
                                        false,                                          // Should interpolate
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault);                     // Intent   

    self = [self initWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is where the problem is:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
```

Shouldn't you be using RGBA here?

Comment: well, there's no CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGBA support :( only CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB

Comment: Sorry, should have checked that first. I checked my previous projects and found that I have been using kCGImageAlphaNone in them.

CGBitmapContextCreate with kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast is supposed to created the correct context. 

just a couple of questions since I too want to find a solution:

1. If some of the transparent areas are ignored, could it be happening because the order of channels somehow goes wrong?

2. Why is kCGImageAlphaLast used in CGImageCreate()?

Comment: well actually I'm not 100% sure, though I do know that if I use kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast  instead of kCGImageAlphaLast I get the following error :  <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 8 integer bits/component; 32 bits/pixel; 3-component color space; kCGImageAlphaLast; 2200 bytes/row.

Comment: Got a similar error when I did not allocate cvMat properly. But I got it running, posted as an answer with code.

Answer (score 1):

```
IplImage *ret = cvLoadImage("file.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```

taking a look at the doc: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED the loaded image will be loaded as is whereas the default argument convert your img to RGB

Comment: I cannot, this is not a file saved on local directory. Rather it's saved in the program's memory. Saving the image to a file and loading it again will be very inefficient (and I do require some level of efficiency in this method).

Comment: Hum... I am sorry, I didn't pay attention, maybe you should take a look at that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861891/how-do-you-generate-an-rgba-image-in-core-graphics

Comment: Yeah, if you notice in my CreateIplImageFromUIImageWithTransparency I do call kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast as advised in that question